# How to insert lines between Bottom Navigation Items of of MDBottomNavigation?

Tags: python, android, kivy

I am using kivymd framework and want to insert lines between each bottom item of the Bottom Navigation.

The code is from https://kivymd.readthedocs.io/en/latest/components/bottom-navigation/index.html.

Thanks!

```
from kivymd.app import MDApp
from kivy.lang import Builder


class Test(MDApp):

    def build(self):
        self.theme_cls.primary_palette = "Gray"
        return Builder.load_string(
            '''
BoxLayout:
    orientation:'vertical'

    MDToolbar:
        title: 'Bottom navigation'
        md_bg_color: .2, .2, .2, 1
        specific_text_color: 1, 1, 1, 1

    MDBottomNavigation:
        panel_color: .2, .2, .2, 1

        MDBottomNavigationItem:
            name: 'screen 1'
            text: 'Python'
            icon: 'language-python'

            MDLabel:
                text: 'Python'
                halign: 'center'

        MDBottomNavigationItem:
            name: 'screen 2'
            text: 'C++'
            icon: 'language-cpp'

            MDLabel:
                text: 'I programming of C++'
                halign: 'center'

        MDBottomNavigationItem:
            name: 'screen 3'
            text: 'JS'
            icon: 'language-javascript'

            MDLabel:
                text: 'JS'
                halign: 'center'
'''
        )


Test().run()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think there is any easy way to do that, but here is an approach that adds a `Separator` `Widget` between the items in the `MDBottomNavigation`:

```
from kivy.clock import Clock
from kivy.properties import ListProperty
from kivy.uix.widget import Widget
from kivymd.app import MDApp
from kivy.lang import Builder

class Separator(Widget):
    sep_color = ListProperty([1,0,0,1])

class Test(MDApp):

    def add_seps(self, dt):
        tab_bar = self.root.ids.mdbn.ids.tab_bar
        for i in range(len(tab_bar.children)-1, 0, -1):
            tab_bar.add_widget(Separator(size_hint=(None, 1), width=4, sep_color=[0,1,0,1]), index=i)

    def build(self):
        self.theme_cls.primary_palette = "Gray"
        Clock.schedule_once(self.add_seps)
        return Builder.load_string(
            '''

<Separator>:
    canvas:
        Color:
            rgba: self.sep_color
        Rectangle:
            pos: self.pos
            size: self.size
BoxLayout:
    orientation:'vertical'

    MDToolbar:
        title: 'Bottom navigation'
        md_bg_color: .2, .2, .2, 1
        specific_text_color: 1, 1, 1, 1

    MDBottomNavigation:
        id: mdbn
        panel_color: .2, .2, .2, 1

        MDBottomNavigationItem:
            name: 'screen 1'
            text: 'Python'
            icon: 'language-python'

            MDLabel:
                text: 'Python'
                halign: 'center'

        MDBottomNavigationItem:
            name: 'screen 2'
            text: 'C++'
            icon: 'language-cpp'

            MDLabel:
                text: 'I programming of C++'
                halign: 'center'

        MDBottomNavigationItem:
            name: 'screen 3'
            text: 'JS'
            icon: 'language-javascript'

            MDLabel:
                text: 'JS'
                halign: 'center'
'''
        )


Test().run()
```

The `Separator` is just a `Rectangle` of the `sep_color`, and the `add_seps()` method inserts them between the items in the `MDBottomNavigation`. Those items are in a `BoxLayout` that has the `id` "tab_bar".

The `Clock.schedule_once()` calls the `add_seps()` method after the `App` is complete.

I have added the `id` "mdbn" on the `MDBottomNavigation` in your `kv` to make it easier to access that `Widget`.

Answer (score 1):

you can use `MDSeparator` in your KV file:

```
        MDLabel:
            text: "Chips with check:"

        MDSeparator:  <-----------##

        StackLayout:
            size_hint_y: None
            height: self.minimum_height
            spacing: dp(5)

            MDChip:
                label: "Check"
                icon: ""
                check: True
                callback: app.callback
```